# sonataadmin bundle FILTERING FIELDS AND CASE SENSITIVITY Not working . No attached service to type named `doctrine_phpcr_string`

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I try to create case insensitive filtering using sonataadmin bundle and symfony 2 but i get an error.

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.6.*"
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^2.3",
```

here is adminclass

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('name', 'doctrine_phpcr_string', array(
            'compare_case_insensitiv' => false
        ))

    ;
}
```

here is documentation

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-phpcr-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#filtering-fields-and-case-sensitivity

here is my error

```
No attached service to type named `doctrine_phpcr_string`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is solution :)

```
  protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('name', 'doctrine_orm_callback',
                array('callback'   => array($this, 'yourFunction'),
                    'field_type' => 'search'),
                null,
                array('pattern' => '^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,12}$')
            );

    }

    public function yourFunction($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value)
    {
        if (!$value['value']) {
            return;
        }

        $queryBuilder
            ->andWhere("LOWER(u.name) LIKE LOWER(:field)")
            ->setParameter('field', "%{$value['value']}%");

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldnt LOWER(u.name) will force a sequential scan? and if you have a lot of rows, you are in trouble?